# How to find two identical rows and delete BOTH of them? (Not just one duplicate!)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have been looking for a proper way to delete BOTH two identical rows, while I just could realise how to delete just one of them as a duplicate.  Is there any way to delete both?

This is for deleting just duplicate; how can I change it?

JUST EDITED THE ORIGINAL CODE WHICH WAS NOT POSTED COMPELETELY:

```
     function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('check-in');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newData){
      if(row.join() == newData[j].join()){
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign array duplicateIndex for index of j. If you find duplication set push j into duplicateIndex. Delete all rows at duplicateIndex  place from the array.

```
var duplicate = false;
var duplicateIndex =[];
  for(j in newData){
      if(row.join() == newData[j].join()){
        duplicate = true;
        duplicateIndex.push(j);
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
    else{
        foreach(var index in duplicateIndex){
            newData.splice(index, 1); 
        }
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I am not sure what the problem is, but it gives error for line :var duplicateIndex[] =[];

Comment: What line? Show the error plz. DId you find out how to erase row from sheet? var duplicateIndex[] =[]; is typo - should be var duplicateIndex =[];

Comment: @ Polina F, another one is found in line: var duplicateIndex.push(j);    I have not found how to clear that row yet!  clrearContent?

Comment: Sorry wrote it without a compiler. Should be duplicateIndex.push(j); After you posted the complete code I see that you need to delete from newData array at your saved indexes

Comment: @ Polina F , I thought I fixed it, but it keeps giving Syntax error for this line: foreach(var index in duplicateIndex){

Comment: try for(index in duplicateIndex){newData.splice(duplicateIndex[index], 1); }

Comment: Thanks it works;  is there also a way to exclude column A from checking equality from this process;  I mean to just check column B to ...(the end column does not matter) and if identical, then remove both.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept and up vote my answer. I frankly don't know anything about google sheets. Stop at breakpoint and check what you have in row from this line var row = data[i]; if you have an array - just compare row[1] with newData.   if(row[1] == newData[j]){ ... if you want to push into newData - push only row[1] newData.push(row[1]);